# Update Sitecore Contact Programmatically :For Users on a Shared Computer

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, experience-profile

I am using Sitecore API to identify and update the contact with a Member ID value Post login.

But the below code seems to update the interaction to the same contact i.e. If two people are logging in from the same computer.

```
 Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs(Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource, memberId);
 var contact = client.Get<Contact>(new IdentifiedContactReference(anyIdentifier.Source, anyIdentifier.Identifier), new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey));

if (contact != null)
{
    var EmailAddressesFacet = new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress(memberId, true), EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey);
    client.SetFacet<EmailAddressList>(contact, EmailAddressesFacet);
    client.SubmitAsync();
}
```

- Does the IdentifyAs() is implemented above in a incorrect way and does it update the current session with the contact fetched
- Should I delete the ANALYTICS_COOKIE post logout to fix this problem?

Any comments appreciated!